# use an "array" to store objects

Tags: arrays, r, class

I have to use copulas to create a large sample of size n. The problem is that the procedure is time consuming since I have to recreate exactly the same copulas n times.

What I'm trying to find is a way of storing the copulas in a kind of array, so I create the copulas once, store them, and use them n times.

In R, the idea is something like this: fill the upper left diagonal matrix with copulas into some kind of a bi-dimensional container (named Copula)

```
for(r in 1:dimension){
   for(c in 1:(dimension+1-r) ){
        Copula[r,c] = getCopula(copulaStr, Pcopula[r,c])
    }
```

}

, so that then 
I can access the copula i,j (Copula[i,j] )as if it were an array.

The copulas I'm tryinng to sore are:

```
class(getCopula('frankCopula', 2))

[1] "frankCopula"
attr(,"package")
[1] "copula"
```

Comment: Just do a list of list, say the outer list for the rows and the inner list for the columns...

Comment: Do not edit your question to include "answers." if you solve the problem yourself, add a proper answer down below and accept it by clicking the green check mark (it is OK to answer your own question). That way the question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

A may of solving this issue is by creating an array lists

```
mat<-matrix(list(), nrow = dimension, ncol = dimension)
for(r in 1:(dimension+1-r)){
    for(c in 1:dimension){
        mat[[r,c]] = obterCopula(copulaStr, Pcopula[r,c])
    }
}
```